# Undefined variable: products and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

Im trying to display the items in my database on my web page but i get Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and Notice: Undefined variable: products. I searched for an answer but cant find one here is my code

```
     <?php
         foreach ($products as $product):
      ?>
           <blockquote> 
               <p>
                 <?php echo htmlspecialchars($product, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
               </p> 
           </blockquote>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `$product` isn't being set properly. You need to show more code, please.

Comment: exactly as the error message states.

Comment: The notice is pretty self-explanatory. The `$products` variable hasn't been defined before you tried to use it in a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

$products must exists and be a array or a class that can be iterated!

Debug your prepending code and see why $products is not defined!